# ws2801Can I send data in any direction

Tags: wiring

I have bought a series of LED's. I'm working to make a bunch of modular floor panels and I need to be sure that if I flipped the wires around it's not going to screw up the LEDs on me. I'm basically asking can i do this and expect it light up?

[image]

Comment: Datasheet where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot.

### EDIT: From here the explanation changes

The WS28** chips delay the signal you give them by the amount of bits they need to control the LEDs to allow you to chain them and then clock in data in a huge stream and rely on them all taking the right amount of data from the stream and all being predictable (to within certain limits, many of those chips in the series have some "undocumented features" when it comes to timing).

This means that the device output is an on-board generated HARD logic output and the input is an on-board terminated input. It would be much like connecting a chain of logic gates like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTG2EX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

### END of EDIT (Thanks to Ignacio for pointing out my inattention to the picture evidence provided)

What you can do?

Drink a cup of coffee or tea and pay attention for a couple of hours while hooking them up, testing it at a very safely limited current power supply (if possible after each addition to find mistakes *immediately*) and then depend on the fact that once hooked up you are never going to have to think about it any more anyway.

Comment: Everything you've said is correct, but the asker is actually swapping input and output, not power and clock and data.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Fair dues. Late-afternoon stupidity on my part. Changing in 3...2...1...

Comment: Thank you both for answering my question. This helps a lot. It seems so obvious when you drew it the way you did. Thank you.

Comment: @tisaconundrum Lengthy explanations and many illustrations are sort of my Jam :-)